# Tweepy library error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_access_token'

Tags: python, tweepy

I am new to programming and python. While taking data from Twitter I am getting this error.
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_access_token'

Here is my code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener 

c_key = '' 
c_secret_key = ''
a_token = ''
a_secret_token = ''

class listner(StreamListener):
    def on_status(self,data):
        print (data)
        return true

    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)

auth = (c_key, c_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(a_token, a_secret_key)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listner())
twitterStream.filter(track = ["facebook"])
```

Comment: Like the error says, `(c_key, c_secret_key)` defines a tuple. Did you mean to instantiate a class there, eg `OAuthHandler(c_key, c_secret_key)`?

Comment: Thanks@ Daniel Roseman ... I missed instantiating class now it is working.